# ¿Cómo poner una imagen de forma vertical?

Tags: html

Estoy colocando unas imágenes en el `html` y pues originalmente la imagen es vertical y cuando la pongo se pone horizontal, entonces sí alguien sabe como ponerla de forma vertical, me ayuda mucho.

`HTML`

```
<img src="../images/fachada2.jpg" class="rounded float-left" style="width: 200px" alt="fachada de lejos">
<img src="../images/pasillo.jpg" class="text-center rounded" style="width: 200px" alt="pasillo">
<img src="../images/fachada_cerc.jpg" class="rounded float-right" style="width: 200px" alt="fachada de cerca">
```

Comment: probaste agregando "vertical-align:middle"?

Comment: Voy a probarlo, ya te digo

Comment: No funciono con eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es extraño que te cambie la orientación de la imagen original pero, podrías probar con este css:

```
<style>
 .rot90 {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
</style>
```

Y luego en tu etiqueta de imagen agregas la clase ".rot90"

```
<img src="../images/fachada2.jpg" class="rounded float-left rot90" style="width: 200px" alt="fachada de lejos">
```

Comment: Listo, amigo, gracias, no tengo ni idea por qué pasó

Comment: Excelente, lo importante es que funcione. Saludos